# I get an EFAULT error from open after using file_name equ "a.txt"?

Tags: assembly, runtime-error, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

I got an error message when running my assembly x86-64 program called `time2.asm`.

I am using Ubuntu x86-64.

after executing sys_open syscall, rax register changes its value to -14 - which means efault error or "bad address".

my code purpose it to open a file called "a.txt" , check if error happen and if not,  close the file.

my code:

```
section .data

file_name equ "a.txt"

section .text

global _start
_start:

 ;--------------------------------------------------------------------
 ; first step-  I open a file called a.txt.

  mov rax, 2         ; sys_open
  mov rdi, file_name
  mov rsi, 0
  mov rdx, 0644q
  syscall        

  ;right after this syscall (sys_open), rax value changes to -14.


  cmp rax,0
  jl error        ;checks for error

  mov rdi,rax
  mov rax,3       ; sys_close
  syscall
  ;----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 error: mov rax,60
 mov rdi,0
 syscall ; exit program
```

Comment: `file_name equ "a.txt"` is wrong, I am surprised it even assembles. Try `file_name db "a.txt", 0` instead.

Comment: @Jester: It's a numeric constant: NASM allows multi-character constants in any context where a numeric literal is accepted.  e.g. `mov eax, '1234'` gives you 4 ASCII characters in a register.

Answer (score 2):

`file_name equ "a.txt"` defines `file_name` as a assemble-time-only **numeric constant**<sup>1</sup>.  It doesn't matter what section this directive appears in; it doesn't assemble any bytes into the output.  `equ` is purely an assemble-time-constant thing.  Similar to `%define` string substitution, but it evaluates the expression to a number on the spot.  (This matters for an expression involving `$`, like `msglen equ $ - msg`.)

**But you need your string in memory, and to pass the system call a *pointer* to a 0-terminated (implicit-length) C string**.  The system-call interface only takes pointers, not values; otherwise it wouldn't be able to handle filenames longer than 8 bytes.  (Or 4 bytes in 32-bit systems).

Thus

```
default rel
section .rodata                  ; read-only data doesn't need to be in read-write .data

file_name: db "a.txt", 0         ; the 0 terminator is important, this is a C string.

section .text
...
    lea     rdi, [file_name]   ;or mov rsi, file_name for the inefficient way
```

The standard way to put static addresses into registers in x86-64 is a RIP-relative LEA.  (`default rel`).  `mov edi, symbol` works in non-PIE executables, but there's basically never a reason to use `mov rdi, symbol` (10-byte `mov r64, imm64`).

---

Footnote 1:

NASM allows multi-character constants in any context where a numeric literal is accepted.  e.g. `mov rax, 'a.txt'` is exactly equivalent to `mov rax, 0x7478742e61`, so `mov [mem], rax` would put the string into memory (because x86 is little-endian), followed by 3 bytes of zeros.

**`file_name equ "a.txt"` is exactly equivalent to `file_name equ 0x7478742e61`**